# Apollo server didn't print errors on node console

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I have an Apollo server:

```
45 const server = new ApolloServer({
46   resolvers,
47   typeDefs, 
48   debug: true,
49 })
```

On the client, I am getting an js error like:

> extensions: {code: "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",…}
>   locations: [{line: 3, column: 7}]
>   0: {line: 3, column: 7}
>   message: "Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"

but node console where the server is running didn't print anything:

> node:63865) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
>    Server ready at http://localhost:4001/
>   Mongoose default connection open to mongodb://localhost/gepick
>   (node:63865) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
>   (node:63865) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead

Answer (score 3):

According to the official doc: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/errors/#for-the-client-response

When initialize the `ApoloServer`, add the `formatError: (err) => {...}` property  will print out the errors, see below:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  formatError: (err) => {
    console.error(err);
    return err;
  },
});
```

Comment: Edit: it did not work because I did setup formatError in the wrong file :) Your answer is correct, no message will print if you don't setup this function explicitly. This is surprisingly not very clear in the documentation, as in development we would expect this behaviour to be the default. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Errors that occur during the resolution of a field are execution errors. Unless you catch the error yourself, it will be caught by GraphQL and returned as part of the response inside the `errors` array, as you are seeing. Because the error is caught, it will never show up in the console.

As long as the `debug` option is set to true and your `NODE_ENV` is `development`, the errors returned will include the stack trace inside the response as well. You've truncated the error in your post, but the stack trace should be found at the following path: `errors[0]extensions.exception.stacktrace`.

The returned error should also include a `path` property that should point to whichever resolver the issue is happening in.

Comment: [Last time I tried this](https://spectrum.chat/apollo/apollo-server/how-can-i-find-the-actual-source-of-an-error-in-my-resolver~fb74bee7-29dd-41fe-b825-f21d2b59c1e4), the stack trace only pointed to Apollo internals, making the trace not very useful. Has the situation been improved in the meantime?

Comment: @DanDascalescu If it's a bug related to the Apollo code (as in that case) then it will point to that code.